# Disable embedded art/cover on music playback in mplayer

Tags: mplayer

folks.
Recently I noticed, that console mplayer started to show embedded art/cover during music playback if there are some. Not it just produce a useless window, it will actually somehow heavily load my system only by showing a static 500x500 image, making fan go loud. I did a search on how to disable embedded art, but only solution found was to provide `-novideo` option. This does not work as expected if passed to ~/.mplayer/config as it will permanently disable all video including legit cases when video is actually needed. Is there is any other configuration option on disabling this just for music files (flac in my case) without affecting video files?

Thanks.

Comment: Super annoying!  The window cannot be closed, lest mplayer will shut down.  When I do `mplayer album/*.flac`, the window pops up and steals focus and my key strokes if I'm typing.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the same and this [solution](https://kenfallon.com/stopping-mplayer-from-displaying-album-art-on-music-or-podcasts/) worked fine for me:

- Add the flag "-vo null".
  -> mplayer -vo null /PATH_TO_AUDIO_FILE

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).